# Prevent UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer when a touch is in a UIBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer, uibarbuttonitem, uinavigationitem

I've been struggling to try to solve this issue I have. I tried to find an answer first here on StackOverflow, but I couldn't find any (although I thought I was on the right track.)

So the issue I'm having is that I have UIBarButtonItems in my UINavigationController's UINavigationBar's UINavigationItem, and when the user touches them, I need to not allow my UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer to trigger by any means.

I've tried several things, to no avail. It seems I cannot find the touch for the UIBarButtonItem, which is pretty sure what I need to be doing.

If you can help me I'd truly appreciate it. Thank you!

**Edit: see my answer below**

Code:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
    if ([touch.view.class isSubclassOfClass:[UIControl class]])
    {
        NSLog(@"This is being called, but gesture is still recognized");
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: "It seems I cannot find the touch for the UIBarButtonItem" Touch is a feature of UIView. UIBarButtonItem is not a UIView! It's not UIControl! Look at the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue using the custom UIView property of UIBarButtonItem instead unfortunately, since UIBarButtonItem is a joke for trying to handle any touch events.

Code:

```
    UIButton *theButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
    theButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 36, 36);
    [theButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showVC:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [theButton setTintColor:[UIColor companyBlue]];
    [theButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Button"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    theButton.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-2, 0, 0, 10);

    [theButton addTarget:self action:@selector(enableEdgeRecognizers:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [theButton addTarget:self action:@selector(disableEdgeRecognizers:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [theButton addTarget:self action:@selector(enableEdgeRecognizers:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpOutside];

- (void)disableEdgeRecognizers:(UIButton *)button
{
    self.VC1ViewRecognizer.enabled = NO;
    self.VC2ViewRecognizer.enabled = NO;
}

- (void)enableEdgeRecognizers:(UIButton *)button
{
    self.VC1ViewRecognizer.enabled = YES;
    self.VC2ViewRecognizer.enabled = YES;
}
```

Comment: It's not "a joke". It's not a UIView so it has no customizable touch at all. Your solution is reasonable and correct but there is no need to act like you've been assaulted by UIBarButtonItem here. :)

Comment: It is a joke because Apple needs to make it UIView based

Comment: It is UIView based if you create it with `initWithCustomView:`, because that way the custom UIView is completely up to you. Otherwise it is not, because that way you have a nice lightweight object that behaves sort of like a button. You have the choice. This is not a good reason for complaining.

Comment: More lightweight than a UIButton? What is the weight of a UIBarButtonItem in comparison?

Comment: It's not a UIView, which is a huge reduction right there (no backing store needed). Then, as another way of thinking about it, look at the methods of UIResponder, UIView, UIControl, and UIButton. Now compare that with the methods of UIBarButtonItem and UIBarItem.

Comment: That's good info to know. Digging around, I see UIControl.h is in UIBarButtonItem's header.